# Instagram stopped working in phone

Tags: instagram

I downloaded instagram from google playstore and installed instagram in my phone. But there is a problem starting instagram it says  please uninstall and reinstall instagram.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you don't check install from unknow source in secret in your settings

or maybe your android version is low to load instagram

or maybe file is crash

download it from another place and then install it